# How do I target this with nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

How do I target the following...

Every **href** attribute, inside a li, inside a ul, inside the FIRST div with the class of "listing".

There are many div.listing divs on the page, and inside each there are like 1000 ul>li>a[href="http://whatever.com"]

I want to fetch all the http://whatever.com in only the first div.

I know I can use div[1] and I can use div[@class="listing"] but really I need to find out how to combine them, and I also need to know how you fetch the attribute and not the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "listing", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]//a/@href
```

I got this by [marking up your question in HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/NyQYY/) and using [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com)

Comment: awesome! never knew about that